# Custom Exception Message in apex Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, apex

I want to create a custom exception. In this exception I want to make a constructor which take one string arguments and append in `getMessage` .How to accomplish this.

```
 public class TimelineException extends Exception{
  private String message;
    public override String getMessage(){
      return 'Not able to post to Timeline.getting response from Api : '+ message;
    }
  }
```

Main problem I am facing is when I use this:

```
public TimelineException(Sting x){
}
```

then its give me error

> Save error: System exception constructor already defined: (String)   GMirror.cls /Google Salesforce Integration/src/classes.

Comment: .You can come to new site for salesforce specific questions.http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to implement something. Just create a your exception class which would extends  salesforce Exception class.

```apex
public class CommonException extends Exception {}
```

then just use it as other exception classes

```apex
try {
    throw new CommonException('Test Common Exception');
} catch(CommonException ex) {
    System.debug(ex.getMessage());        
}
```

console output:

`09:18:55:059 USER_DEBUG [4]|DEBUG|Test Common Exception`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `try` statement in your controller:

```
try
{
    // What you are trying to do
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    system.debug(e.getStackTraceString());
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'special friendly message to user'));
}
```

Then in the `visualForce` page you write `apex:messages/` where you want the message to be displayed.